# controller not get a reference of a view

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I make a simple MVC application, have one 'app.js'

```
Ext.application({
name: 'ImpPdf',

extend: 'ImpPdf.Application',

autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

have one 'application.js'

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.Application', {
name: 'ImpPdf',

extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

views: [
    'Main'
],

controllers: [
    'Main'
],

stores: []
});
```

Have a 'viewport.js'

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
requires:[
    'Ext.layout.container.Fit',
    'ImpPdf.view.Main'
],

layout: {
    type: 'fit'
},

items: [{
    xtype: 'app-main'
}]
});
```

Have a controller 'Main.js'

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: 'Main',
refs: [
    { ref: 'appMain', selector: 'appmain', xtype: 'app-main' }
],

init: function() {

    console.log('Main.Controle');
    console.log(this.getAppMain());

    this.control({
        'appmain tabpanel': {
            click: this.onTabChange
        }
    });
},
onTabChange: function(tabPanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
    console.log('tabchange');
}

});
```

Have a view 'Main.js'

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
requires:[
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    'Ext.layout.*',
    'Ext.ux.GroupTabPanel'
],
alias: 'widget.appmain',
xtype: 'app-main',

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},
defaults: {
    bodyBorde: false,
    split: true,
    bodyPadding: 0
},
items: [
    header,
    west,
    contentPanel
]
});
```

The problem is, I cannot get the reference to a view in controller. 
Console show me undefined. console.log(this.getAppMain());

I need to get a tabpanel' to get a 'tabchange' event.

Answer (score 0):

The alias & the are synonymous:

```
alias: 'widget.appmain',
xtype: 'app-main',
```

They should be the same thing, and the selector should match only one.

Comment: Thank you, i changed, using only one but nothing changed.

Comment: No, they're not the same. There's a subtle difference that can lead to confusion. I explain in my answer.

Comment: They should be the same, the `xtype` is inferred (if not explicitly specified) from the `alias`. There's no reason for them to be different.

Comment: You're right, but it is not good to use both alias and xtype simultaneously. It makes no sense. Also your code is easier to read if you use xtype exclusively for **referencing** a component and alias to **define** the xtype.

Answer (score 0):

The xtype of the view is app-main, your ref should be :

```
refs: [
    { ref: 'appMain', selector: 'app-main' }
]
```

The getter created by the ref is getAppMain()

Also note that you should not use xtype and alias together. Here's the difference :

xtype is a reference to a component. It is used to define a sub component.

alias is a config of a component. It defines its xtype, that can be used in a component query as a selector ( like ref does ).

```
Ext.define('myForm', {
    alias: 'widget.myForm',
    items: [
        {xtype: 'button'},
        {xtype: 'textfield'}
    ]
```

It is possible to replace alias: 'widget.myForm' by xtype: 'myForm', they are synonyms in this special case. Both will do the same thing, but it is confusing, because you use xtype for two completly different things (reference a component and define it's xtype by which it will be referenced).

To resume : alias defines the xtype, the selector property of ref uses component queries to select the component returned by the getter.